# Sidebar links on the "ask question"-page should open in a new tab

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, sidebar

The sidebar links on the "Ask question"-page should open in a new tab, instead of the same window. The "formatting help"-link already does so, but all others ("visit the help center", "asking help", "popular tags") move away from the asking page. Most current browsers will restore the already-entered question text, but there's a real chance the user could lose the text that he/she has already entered.

Comment: No loss, there is a draft being saved. Did you check it yourself?

Comment: The "You have started writing or editing a post"-JS-alert doesn't always show up, and comments aren't being saved as drafts, for example  (and can't be resurrected by the browser's back-button, even).

Comment: Comments are minor thing, you should not write important things in them to begin with. As for JS alert that's not what I mean. Go now to "ask a question" page on Stack Overflow here on Meta and type something in title and body. Leave the page. Get back to it, and you'll see what you typed.

Answer (score 6):

No, we shouldn't decide for our users how links open up.

All modern browsers have a facility to allow the user to decide how to open a link - Ctrl clicking, middle clicking or however else.

We will not make the decision for people.

Formatting help is one of the very few places we do so as we know that someone is in mid-edit and is looking for information - we do not want them to lose their place.